# how to fadeIn/fadeOut with if statement in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, fadein, fadeout

Im stuck on my fadeIn/fadeOut effect.

I can get the effect going fine, its just the stopping/starting I'm having trouble with.
I have tried `stop()` too with no success.

The current code I'm working with can be found here: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmYRP/1/)

What I am doing is checking if the `div` has a specific class, if so, then I'm fading in a 'share' option. This is done by `hover()` in jQuery. There's a catch however, that is, the 'share' link must relate to a specific id which is caught by the `hover()`

For those who need the code on here; 
**jQuery**

```
$("[name=fluid-success]").hover(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var button = $(this).find(".share" + id);
    if (button.length > 0) {
        button.fadeIn();
        //button.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**sample HTML;**

```
<div class="row-fluid" name="fluid-success" id="1">
    <div class="span9">a result</div>
    <div class="span3"> <a class="pull-right share1" style="display:none" href="#">Share<i class="icon-share"></i></a>
    </div>
```

If I'm honest, I'm not too sure if I am going the right way about this.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$("[name=fluid-success]").mouseenter(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var button = $(this).find(".share" + id);
    if (button.length > 0) {
        button.fadeIn();
        //button.fadeOut();
    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
//fadeout stuff
});
```

here's a working fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jmYRP/7/

you also might want to look into managing event queuing http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/ or at least passing a speed with which to fade in/out like so `.fadeIn(150)`

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `a` that has the same parent id as the div you are hovering over using the selector `$('a', this)`. The jQuery would then look as follows:

```
$("[name=fluid-success]").hover(function () {
    if (($('a', this)).length > 0) {
        $('a', this).fadeIn(400);
    }
},

function () {
    $('a', this).fadeOut(400);
});
```

(I've added a time to the fadeIn/fadeOut so you can see the animation effect).

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmYRP/8/

Comment: your code will fade any anchor tags inside the row, not just the share links

Comment: @koala_dev fair enough. In the example html there is only one `a` tag inside the div, but the code could be easily modified if that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things by giving a common class to your share links and then finding the one inside the row you're hovering.

```
$("[name=fluid-success]").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.share').stop().fadeIn();
},
function () {
    $(this).find('.share').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

By passing [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) two function arguments, the first handles the mouseenter event while the second handles the mousleeave.

Calling [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) in both instances will stop any currently-running animation and will prevent the enlarging of the effects queue

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmYRP/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

here is your jsfiddle - redone. I just made two functions for this and it works without problems cross-browser.

```
$("[name=fluid-success]").mouseenter(function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var button = $(this).find(".share" + id);
if (button.length > 0) {
    button.fadeIn();
}
});

$("[name=fluid-success]").mouseleave(function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var button = $(this).find(".share" + id);
if (button.length > 0) {
    button.fadeOut();
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95TAS/